# Eigenvectors sign in $\rm NH_3$ Molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, molecules

Let's consider an $\rm NH_3$ molecule.
The Hamiltonian in the $\{|\psi_L>,|\psi_R>\}$ basis can be written as:

$$\hat{H}=\begin{pmatrix}
E_0 & -A \\
-A & E_0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now by diagonalizing this operator we can find the following eigenvalues:

$$E_S=E_0-A$$
$$E_A=E_0+A$$

And their respective eigenkets:

$$|S>= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \  $$
$$|A>= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \ $$
And thus if we consider $|\psi_L>=(1,0)$ and $|\psi_R>=(0,1)$ :
$$|S>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi_L>+|\psi_R>)$$
$$|A>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi_L>-|\psi_R>)$$
**My question is why do we take this specific order for signs for $|A>$ and not for example $|A>=(-1,1)$**

Comment: It makes no difference. $\pm |A\rangle$ are both the same physical state.

Comment: If $|A\rangle$ is a (normalized) eigenvector of some operator, also $e^{i \alpha} |A\rangle$ with an arbitrary real phase angle $\alpha$ is still an eigenvector (with the same eigenvalue). Take what you like best, it does not change the physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some (normalized) eigenvector is valid, multiplying it by any complex phase doesn’t change that is a normalized eigenvector.
Say
$$Av =\lambda v$$

Then for complex $\alpha =e^{i\phi}$

$$A(\alpha v) = \alpha Av=\alpha\lambda v=\lambda(\alpha v)$$ Notice that the eigenvalue of $\alpha v $ is still just $\lambda$. If we didn’t care about normalization, the argument holds exactly for any non-zero complex number $\alpha$.